# Uptime checks for IPv6

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ipv6, google-cloud-monitoring

We recently had some issues with our IPv6 acceptance which resulted in our website to be offline for all users, that have a IPv6 address. Even if these people have an IPv4 address too, they were getting an error, as IPv6 is being preferred.
Our Google Monitoring Uptime check did not trigger, as it is only checking the IPv4 connection.

Is there a way to check IPv4 AND IPv6 with Uptime check?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not an answer but I use an external service. You will get better reports with more options.

Comment: I have a solution to suggest you to use [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/solution/server-uptime-monitoring/) to Monitor Your IPv6 Enabled Websites. Whenever your website goes offline this [doc](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/success_center/pingdom/content/topics/ipv6-monitoring.htm) sends you an alert to make sure to act on it.
Follow this to [enable monitoring](https://www.pingdom.com/blog/pingdom-adds-two-new-features-asia-pacific-probe-servers-and-ipv6-monitoring/) for  IPV6.